# Why does Lambda configured within a VPC, same as ec2 cannot send an api request to a nomad client within the instance?

Tags: aws-lambda, devops

When I send a post API request to a Nomad client inside an ec2 instance within the same VPC, I get a connection timeout error (*Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/jobs (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to dns_name.net timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))*).

Even though I configured lambda according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html but it still does not seem to reach the Nomad client.

I already checked with the Nat gateway configuration, that seems to work fine.

Comment: Hey DevOps90 welcome to stack, when you got to your EC2 instance you have security groups, have you allowed access from your lambda subnets?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying @mrk Fldig. I had security group set to default, it allows all the traffic. However, I found the problem now. I was using DNS address but I need to send api request to individual nomad servers, for that I need to get the list of private ips and send a request to each of these ips individually. This works for now.

Comment: Heya, so you need to assign an elastic IP so it gets a static IP address.